# How to mock jdbctemplate.query() method?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
Mokito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ParticipantMapper())).thenReturn(participantExistingList);
```

I am using above line of code for Mocking jdbcTemplate but its not working. Can some one will help how to mock jdbcTemplate.

Comment: Use `Mockito.any(ParticipantMapper.class)` instead of `new ParticipantMapper()`

Comment: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:  Getting this error after adding above code.

Answer (score 5):

Use ArgumentMatchers for all Arguments, like this:

```
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(any(String.class), any(ParticipantMapper.class)))
.thenReturn(participantExistingList);
```

Depending on your wish to focus the interaction, you may use e.g. `eq()` for your sql String.

See [here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html) for JavaDoc.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this:

On your test class use:

```
    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Then try:

```
Mokito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ParticipantMapper())).thenReturn(participantExistingList);
```

If it still fails, try:

```
doReturn(participantExistingList).when(jdbcTemplate).query(sql, new ParticipantMapper());
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Its important to see the **order of your parameters inside query() method.**

In my case, I wanted to mock for the following line:

```
List<String> someList = jdbcTemplate.query(SQL_STRING,new Object[] { Id }, new MyCustomMapper());
```

So I mocked it the following way, **taking care of the order of parameters passed**

```
when(jdbcTemplate.query(any(String.class),(Object[]) anyVararg(),any(MyCustomMapper.class))).thenReturn(myList);
```