# Using Mockito, how do I match against the key-value pair of a map in a list?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have the following List which should be returned by Mockito when `queryForList` is called!
But I get a NullPointerException. What is the best practice to use Mockito here?

```
@Mock
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> row= new HashMap<>();
    row.put("id", id);
    row.put("user", user);
    row.put("name", name);

    result.add(row);

 Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForList( any(),anyMap() )).thenReturn(result);

 methodWhichCallsJDBC_TemplateQueryForList();
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.one.MethodTest.methodWhichCallsJDBC_TemplateQueryForList(MethodTest.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Comment: see if this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276101/how-to-mock-jdbctemplate-query-method

Are you injectingMocks?  is jdbcTemplate a @Mock?

Comment: *Where* do you get the NPE? Please include your stacktrace. Have you initialized your mock of `jdbcTemplate`?

Comment: jdbcTemplate is a @Mock yes, Stacktrace added to question